# How do I change a Qt widget's geometry while maintaining its children's positions on screen?

Tags: qt, pyqt, widget, flicker

I have a widget with a child widget inside. The size of the main widget can be changed at run time because I need some extra area to paint some dynamic contents, and when finished I would like it to restore its previous size.

When the widget changes its size, **the child widget should stay exactly where it is**. I tried to implement this by moving the main widget and its child simultaneously so that when both were moved the child's position on screen remained the same, but that caused **flickers** quite often.

I prefer not to let the main widget have a large fixed size reserving space for those dynamic contents, since they can appear in any direction, which causes that size to be pretty huge and may have some side effects.

How can I get rid of those flickers? Or is there any better approach? **Any help will be appreciated.**

Here's the code (clicking on the image toggles the size):

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint, QSize
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPixmap

import sys


class Child(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setFixedSize(100, 100)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        # the longer it costs to paint, the easier it is to reproduce the flicker
        for i in range(500):
            painter.drawPixmap(event.rect(), QPixmap("some picture"))
        painter.end()


class MyWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._state = 0
        self._child = Child(self)
        self._child.move(0, 0)
        self.setFixedSize(100, 100)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            delta = QPoint(50, 50)
            if self._state:
                delta = -delta
            self._state ^= 1

            self._child.move(self._child.pos() + delta)
            self.setFixedSize(self.size() + QSize(delta.x(), delta.y()))
            self.move(self.pos() - delta)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWidget()
    w.move(200, 200)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What you want is for the child widget to maintain its fixed position with respect to the screen even when the parent moves. Am I right? if it is so because you emulate the task of painting with a for loop, I think that it is that part that is wrong but as you give details it is difficult to solve.

Comment: One way to avoid that the task of the painting takes a long time is to create an alternative QPixmap where the painting is done, and that qpixmap is the one that at the end is used to paint the widget in the paintEvent method.

Comment: @eyllanesc You're right. But that for loop was used to make it easier to reproduce the flicker and was not actually in my code. Even if I make the painting task simple enough there is still chance that the flicker may occur. And I'm wondering if there's some better way to eliminate the flicker problem since the time that the painting costs is not something I can really rely upon.

Comment: The problem is that every time you move a widget it repaints itself and also the children. Can I assume that the painting task is not heavy?

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes you can. It's not.